# add "flair" next to certain wordpress usernames

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Like the title says I want to add "flair" next to certain (not all) users in my wordpress site. Very similar to how reddit does it but to be used more for how YouTube has added "verified" users (essentially what I'll be using it for).

YouTube & Reddit examples - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXvg1.jpg

I have the css for hovering so it changes color but I don't know how to make it stay to the right of the text/username.

**CSS**

```
#verified {left: 10px; width: 9px;}
#verified {background: url(verifieds.png) 0 0;}
#verified:hover {background: url(verifieds.png) 0 -9px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="verified">test</p>
```

This is giving me this as a result: http://jirachi.net/hover/hover.html but the hovering to change works somewhat. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this, [see demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/FrBYG/)

```
#verified {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    width:35px;
    height:18px;
    background: url(http://jirachi.net/hover/verifieds.png) no-repeat right center;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#verified:hover {
    background: url(http://jirachi.net/hover/verifieds.png) repeat-y right -9px;
}
```

Comment: The positioning is good but it is there twice, one on top of each other. I don't know if it's possible to only have one? Should I break up the image into 2 separate ones for this to be easier?

Answer (score -1):

so after the user hovers over verified you want the background to stay 0 -9px?  if that's the case just add

```
#verified:active,
```

before #verified:hover

Comment: ??? could you explain that? Perhaps with a fiddle? the 'before' makes no sense to me at all, and i don't see what the ':active' has to do with it...

Comment: that is not true. :active is the selector for the pressed state, the one that is shown while the mouse button is down on the element. Will make absolutely no difference here!